# How to get the href of selected/active tab using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <div id="filter-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#image" class="current"><?php _e('Image','sofa'); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#text"><?php _e('Text','sofa'); ?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#video"><?php _e('Video','sofa'); ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

How can I get the href value of list which has class current? e.g. How can I make it return `image` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `attr` or `prop` methods:

```
$("#filter-bar .current").attr("href");
```

or

```
$("#filter-bar .current").prop("href");
```

You can get "pure" `href` without hash `#` sign with this:

```
var href = $("#filter-bar .current").attr("href");
href = href.substring(href.indexOf("#") + 1);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BJd7p/

Comment: And how to eliminate the # besides the link?

Comment: @AhmedFouad You can get the solution from the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get the href without `#` which will be `image` for your markup and that is what you want

```
$('#filter-bar a.current').attr('href').split('#')[1];
```

Read on [$.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/kaNt2/)